# Missing argument 3 for {closure}() in route filter

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-4, controller, routes

I was working with laravel 4.2 and using filter to log all the route requests and their responses. This is basically the method that i was trying to use

[image]

If i remove the response argument from it , it works fine but i also need the response from route, it gives me this error when i add that arguemnt to the method

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error when `$response` is not given .

You can solve this easily by giving `$response` a default value. **Rest is up to your logic.**

```
Route :: filter('log', function($route, $request, $response = null) {

});
```